# unable to compile samples obtained from Restlet.org

Tags: java, restlet

When I try to compile the sample using sources.zip found at 
http://www.restlet.org/documentation/1.1/firstSteps

Here is the detail

`C:\mwb\srvr\firstSteps10>javac -classpath "C:\Program Files\Restlet Framework\Edition Java SE\2.0.14\src\org.restlet" ServerApp10.java ServerResource10.java
 Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
 Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
 Note: C:\Program Files\Restlet Framework\Edition Java SE\2.0.14\src\org.restlet\org\restlet\service\TaskService.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
 Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.`

I have java version "1.7.0_05"
I tried restlet 2.0.14 and 2.1 RC5

please let me know what am I missing here - any suggestions or pointers?

Comment: I'd suggest using the eclipse IDE.

Comment: @ftom2 - Eclipse IDE is for OSGI edition only? I am interested in Java SE

Comment: no, you can use it for any kind of java development. you can even download prepared bundles for certain purposes. I recommend the Java EE bundle.

Comment: @ftom2 - it worked well with Eclipse - Thanks a lot. Make your comment available as an answer - I will accept it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) to compile and develop. I suggest you download the Java EE version.